# Generate product of two primes that starts with 1234

Tags: number-theory

A polynomial time algorithm to generate a composite number $N$ that starts with 1234 and has two prime factors. Each prime factor should have about $n$ digits with $n\approx 100$.

To generalize, The starting sequence is arbitrary but has $O(\log N)$ digits.

The question is to give such an algorithm or show it is as difficult as the general factorization problem.

Comment: compost $\mapsto$ composite $\;$

Comment: also: What about such an algorithm? $\;$

Comment: ...and the question is...?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind: $1234002554600399 = 10000019 \times 123400021$. It can be easily extended to $100$ digits.

The algorithm, as should be obvious from the example, is as follows:

1. Generate the next prime after $1234000\cdots0$. This requires polynomial time operation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test.
2. Generate the next prime after $100\cdots0$. Again this requires polynomial time.
3. Multiply in polynomial time.

As someone has noted in the comments, this is not a proof since  the prime gap conjecture has not been proven. But in practice, the conjecture is only questionable for numbers with well over 100 digits, say $10^{100}$ digits. For numbers in 100 digit range, it takes fraction of a second to compute the next prime.

A much more interesting question, which was my intention, is to come up with such factors when one of them is chosen at random. The solution of that problem is similar the one I gave as long as the starting digits of $N$ is sufficiently short. For example, for the random prime $p=3686291308889107916563946018842923764851383444210760336073350453165756782523308‌031968158671536820381$
 we can easily compute prime $q=33475379360940300359873856875072885158829731531859190565216276352555818325164172‌485549389730860958220447$ so that $N=p\cdot q=1234\dots$.

Comment: If you cannot edit your own posts, it is likely because you are inadvertently creating new accounts rather than using the same account. In fact there are three "mhp" accounts on this page. I will flag this for moderator attention, to merge them. In the meantime, please register your account so that you can sign into it rather than creating a new account for each post.

Comment: Although step 1 "requires polynomial time operations", it's still important _how many_ of them it requires. $\:$ If it requires super-polynomially many of them, then the fact that the operations are polynomial time is, one might say, not particularly useful. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: It is not proven yet that prime gaps are bounded by a polynomial term. But it highly conjectured so this is most likely true.

Comment: For a polynomial time algorithm, you would need polynomial time operation to _suffice_ for the steps. $\hspace{.39 in}$ It is (not necessary and) not sufficient that polynomial time operation is _required_ for the steps. $\hspace{.72 in}$